# Using JQuery to grab a file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a custom file upload button in my web app. I want the user to see that they have chosen a file so I change the html of a div to show the file name.

Here is my jquery:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    var filename = $("input[type=file]").val();
    $("#share-file-name p").html(filename);
});
```

Now, this works great, except for the fact that the value of the input is:

```
C:\fakepath\photo.jpg
```

So that's what the user sees. I just want them to see the "photo.jpg" part. How can I use my jquery to strip everything except for the file name?

Thanks!

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: use string manipulation, not jQuery.

Comment: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: `filename.split('\').pop();`

Comment: Most of the answers below assume that all of your users are on Windows. The best answer is that which includes the regex '/[\/\\\]/' which will work for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
filename = filename.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just chop off anything to the left of the rightmost "/"

like so:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    var filename = $("input[type=file]").val();
    // As pointed out in the comments, this line is required to make it
    // Windows compliant. It's important to handle paths from any OS.
    filename = filename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    $("#share-file-name p").html(filename);
});
```

Comment: doesn't work on windows, but hey it's only 90% of the market...

Comment: @dandavis which browser did you test it in that it didn't work? This is standard JavaScript, and it should work on all major browsers.

Comment: it's not the JS, it's the backwards path symbol that breaks...

Comment: Ah, you're quite right. I went ahead and fixed it, so it should work anywhere now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the full file path stored in a variable `filename`, you can do the following to get only the file name:

```
filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("\"))
```

Regular expressions or the split command are overkill for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

use `split("/");` and then you got an array with all elements separated by / so the last element will be the file name

```
var file = filepath.split("/"); file[file.length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
 filnameToDisplay = /([^\\]+.\w+$)/.exec(filename)[0];
```

This will get what you want regardless of length of the filepath or characters in the filename, unless they are using a strange extension I don't know about!